# It is possible to draw an object in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, draw, sap-fiori

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to draw something in SAPUI5, using JavaScript, like, for example, draw a circle, and then, move it around the screen to the position I want?

I'm not really a JS developer, but Java. So I don't really know what should I try, to be honest, check out for some info, and didn't find anything.

---

EDIT:

I don't want to use HTML, just JS, XML and CSS if necessary.

---

NEW EDIT:

Okey, I found something that might solve my problem, need more testing. You can add some html to your XML, just like this:

```
    <core:HTML id="html"></core:HTML>
```

Once we have this HTML on our XML, we can add content to it, in JS, would look like this:

```
onInit: function () {
        this.getView().byId("html").setContent(
            "<canvas id='myCanvas' width='400' height='200' class='signature-pad' style='border:1px solid;'></canvas>");
    }
```

Just with that, we have our Canvas ready, now we just need to add something in it, for that, I just created a button, on pressed, would do the following:

```
onPress: function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);
    }
```

### I'm now trying to move the square, around the canvas. One I finish that part, I'll come to add the code.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!!!

Francisco Donaire.

Comment: Maybe try [drawing a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+draw+circle), then try moving it around and in case of issues update your question?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to draw a circle, but it seems like there is not a library for that on SAPUI5...

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVG for drawing circle or another object in absolute div. Then animate this div with js. I didn't try yet but I think we can use WebGL for more complex drawings.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>SAPUI5</title>
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

<script id="myView" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="MyController" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout">

    <layout:MatrixLayout>
        <layout:rows>
        <layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
            <layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Fill1" padding="None">
                <Button text="Test Button" width="100%"/>
            </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
          <layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Fill2">
                <Button text="Test Button2" />
            </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
        <layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
            <layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Fill3">
                <Button text="Test Button3" />
            </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
          <layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Plain">
                <Button text="Test Button4" />
            </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
      </layout:rows>
    </layout:MatrixLayout>


  </mvc:View>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="position: absolute;top:0">
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Js**

```
 sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
   "use strict";
   sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
     onInit: function() {
        animateDiv('.circle');
     }
   });
   sap.ui.xmlview({
     viewContent: jQuery("#myView").html()
   }).placeAt("content");

 });

function makeNewPosition(){

  // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
  var h = $(window).height() - 50;
  var w = $(window).width() - 50;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(myclass){
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  $(myclass).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, 1000,   function(){
    animateDiv(myclass);        
  });

};
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mkysoft/3ngyk4fw/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mkysoft, I forget to include that I don't want to use HTML, I'm just using the XML, JS, and CSS... I'm so sorry!

Comment: You can create dynamic html element with js. I need some deep search for xml view.

Comment: may be this can help: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3916868

Comment: Hmmm, it's not what I'm looking for, but thanks! I'm going to keep searching for a solution, if I found something, I'll come back!